# Excel chart referring to non-existent sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

We have an Excel Report generated by a Java Process with all charts and jazz. The report has 10 tabs. The very first report has a "Walk Chart" generated. Unfortunately, the chart is displaying incorrect values and it is upon me to fix it. Of course, the original developer is no longer with the company. There is no documentation whatsoever.

When clicked on the chart line, it showed the below for the Data Source.

```
        ='10B. Industrial Models. (2)'!$G$3181:$S$3181
```

However, there is no sheet called "10B Industrial Models (2)". I "Unhid" the sheets and columns, but just cannot find it.
I just cannot figure out how this chart is being generated and where the data source is.

Any ideas on how or where I can further look to figure this out?
Is there a hidden VB code perhaps? Looked at formulas, didnt find anything there..
If its a hidden VB code, how can I find out where it is and what it does?

Any ideas for troubleshooting this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely, it's an artifact or poorly-written code or changes that were made post-development. What have you tried thus far? Have you looked into how to open the Visual Basic Editor? Can you find the Java snippet that creates the chart?

Comment: Hello @EngineerToast Thanks for Responding. Yes, tried to view the code in VB Editor, but didnt find anything. Dug through the Java code as well and nothing here...Hence the post here..

Comment: If the chart doesn't exist before the process is run and *does* exist after, then something creates it. The problem would exist in the code that creates it. Unfortunately, you've been handed an undocumented program and I don't know how to help find the problem as I know far less than you about the program's contents.

Comment: Not a problem @EngineerToast Thank you though for responding. Upon digging further, in the VB code window navigator, there is the sheet I am looking for set as VeryHidden. Setting it to Visible helped display the sheet. Phew! This is such a nested piece of mess.. :)

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about that because I use a macro to unhide all sheets and it works even if it's VeryHidden. Good find!